# How to create a Teradata table by copying and modifying another Table?

Tags: teradatasql

I am trying to create a new Teradata table by copying another table, but also need to add one new column, based on a condition of another column from the old table while copying, can you help me on the code?

```
create Table new_table as 
      (select * 
       from old_table) with data

ALTER TABLE new_table ADD new_col varchar(20) check(new_col in ('National', 'Local')
```

-- there is a column in the old_table with value ( 'Y', 'N'), how can i create the new column in the new_table with this condition: if Y new_col=national, if N, new_col=local?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a check constraint that will immediately be violated. Also note that CREATE TABLE AS (SELECT ...) results in all columns being nullable, and if you don't explicitly state a Primary Index the new table will use system default, e.g. first column alone as PI. A CASE expression can be used to populate the new column.

One possible sequence:

```
create Table new_table as old_table with no data; -- copy index definitions, NOT NULL attributes  

ALTER TABLE new_table ADD new_col varchar(20) check(new_col in ('National', 'Local'));

INSERT new_table SELECT o.*, 
  CASE WHEN o.old_col = 'Y' THEN 'National' ELSE 'Local' END 
FROM old_table o;
```